# Phantom errors Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a physical device connected. When the phone is locked and I deploy the application after unlocking, the application works and everything is fine. But if the screen is unlocked and I deploy I get the following error. In this case, everything is ok on the emulator. Help me understand this nonsense.

```
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

[HotReload] (2021-03-17 23:08:35.2): INFO: Инициализация горячей перезагрузки XAML…
[HotReload] (2021-03-17 23:08:35.2): WARN: (DriverHelper v 2.0.Android) Unknown Breakpoint Hit: Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives( typeName_ptr, int typeName_len,  jniClass,  methods_ptr, int methods_len)

"<unnamed thread>"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception) <0x00007>
  at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException (System.Exception) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/Debugger.cs:125
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.46 (intptr,intptr) [0x00020] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.46 (intptr,intptr) [0x00033] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0

"ProtocolHandler.SendThread"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait (object,int) <0x00007>
  at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (bool,int,object) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs:85
  at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int,bool) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:218
  at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:238
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler/WaitableActionsList.WaitForData () [0x00019] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler.ActionThread (object) [0x00045] in <c37c1589af
144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:78
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/
03-17 23:08:49.317 E/mono    (27416): Full thread dump:referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (object) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:93
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0006b] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0

"<threadpool thread>"
"Debugger agent"
"Thread Pool Worker"
"Thread Pool Worker"
"Thread Pool Worker"
"Timer-Scheduler"
"Finalizer"
"ProtocolHandler.ProcessThread"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait (object,int) <0x00007>
  at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (bool,int,object) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs:85
  at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int,bool) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android

/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:218
  at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:238
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler/WaitableActionsList.WaitForData () [0x00019] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler.ActionThread (object) [0x00045] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:78
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/re
ferencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (object) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:93
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0006b] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0

"ProtocolHandler.ReadThread"  at <unknow
n> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait (object,int) <0x00007>
  at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (bool,int,object) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs:85
  at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int,bool) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:218
  at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:238
  at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.IDataBridge.ReadMessage () [0x0002f] in D:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:341
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler.ReadThread () [0x00038] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c
5e22242>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:74
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource
/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:111
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00067] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0
```

Comment: For some reason, system is calling ThreadStart on a null object (that is supposed to contain a thread). First, power phone off/on. Manually delete app and try again. If you set a breakpoint at the very first line of code that gets executed (maybe in activity OnCreate?), does that breakpoint get reached?  If so, then you should be able to track it down by stepping through code. If not, then turn off "Hot Reload", and try again. Google for other problems related to Hot Reload, or physical devices, or how to ensure all Xamarin related modules are deleted from phone, before trying again.

Comment: If this is a first time you've tried to debug x-forms on this device, it might also be worth building some simple x-forms sample app, and seeing if that works.